# Cronjob to visit each url of a list but not save them

Tags: files, wget

I have a txt file list.txt that have bunch of urls, one every line. I want to set a cron job that wget/curl each url of the file once a day but does not save them in the computer.

I tried to run this on the terminal first.

```
wget -i /root/list.txt -O /dev/null
```

The command doesnt work understandably. It saves the list.txt to /dev/null, not the files from the urls inside list.txt. Then it says "no urls found".

So how do I do it properly? Wget each urls from a list but dont save anything on the computer?

Comment: What is the content of `/root/list.txt`? As which user do you run the `cron`?

Comment: In general `wget` is specifically designed to download content from the web where `curl` is much more versatile and for example allows you to use the [`HEAD` method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-methods) which may  save you on bandwidth and time when you're discarding the output anyway.

Comment: @RomeoNinov "bunch of URLs, one every line"

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to download the URLs, suppress it by using `--spider`. And you can remove the clutter with `-q`, which has the additional benefit the actual errors are still handled by crond and forwarded if set up properly.

```
wget -i /root/list.txt --spider -q
```

Comment: How do I make it work for URLs? This only works for internal files. when I try `wget -i https://example.com/list.txt --spider`, it shows
`example.txt.tmp: No such file or directory
No URLs found in https://example.com/list.txt.`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're using wget here, as the primary goal of that tool is to download file(s).

With curl and a simple loop, it should work, something like this :

```
for i in `cat list.txt`; do curl $i; done
```

And nothing will be downloaded, just a hit on the targeted websites in your text list.

Comment: What if my list.txt has to be sent over HTTP? like https://example.com/list.txt?

Comment: This will actually download the URLs AND print them (which will then be forwarded by cron), just like wget. You want to add `--silent --output /dev/null` to prevent that.